# How to print local pdf file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

For example, I having local pdf file which contains 6 pages. If I using `window.print()`function, In print preview will shown only one page what ever in the browser. Instead of single page I have to show all the pages in print preview mode.

Comment: Friends any answers welcome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bind all the required pages or data around a div and print a div instead and for printing a div you just have to place this much of code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">
    This will be printed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a quam at nibh adipiscing interdum. Nulla vitae accumsan ante. 
</div>

<div>
    This will not be printed.
</div>

<div id="anotherdiv">
    Nor will this.
</div>

<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('#mydiv')" />

</body>
</html>
```